# Argument type 'CLLocationDegrees?' (aka 'Optional<Double>') does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, webview

I am in the process of creating a web application. The application is a kind of map and therefore I need to retrieve the location of the user. In principle this works, but the longitude and latitude must be sent to the server.  I do this with the function updateLocation. At the very bottom it goes wrong. The function locationManager keeps track of whether the location has changed. The new lon and lat should then be sent to the server. Basically, I thought I would do this by calling the updateLocation function from within the locationManager function. Only this doesn't work. I get the following error message here from Xcode:

Argument type 'CLLocationDegrees?' (aka 'Optional') does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg'

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem. PS: I know some of the code may be cumbersome. I am not very familiar with SwiftUI.

**Webview**

```
//
//  WebView.swift
//  ferocity
//
//  Created by Jens Buwalda on 2022-06-17.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import WebKit
import CoreLocation

struct WebView : UIViewRepresentable {

    let url: URL
    var webView = WKWebView()
    var manager = LocationManagerService()
   
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
        return webView
    }
    
    // AND IT HAS TO CALL THIS (OR UPDATE THE WEBVIEW)
    func updateLocation(lat:String, lon:String){
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("deviceLocation(" + lat + ", " + lon + ");")
    }


    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    //Conform to WKNavigationDelegate protocol here and declare its delegate
    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
        var parent: WebView

        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            // Check if there is a token in the url
            let token = getQueryStringParameter(url: navigationAction.request.url!.absoluteString, param: "token")
            // Save token if available
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            if token != nil{
                defaults.set(token, forKey: "token")
            }
            
            // Check if a token is present in storage
            if let memoryToken = defaults.string(forKey: "token") {
                print("Memory token: " + memoryToken)
                // Add token to new url
                let reloadUrl = insertQueryItems(url: navigationAction.request.url!.absoluteString, key: "token", value: memoryToken)!
                print("Reload url: " + reloadUrl.absoluteString)
                // Check if the url id different from the current url
                if navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString != reloadUrl.absoluteString{
                    print("Reload")
                    webView.load(URLRequest(url: reloadUrl))
                }
            } else {
                print("No token in memory")
            }

            
            //Change padding on login page
            if ((navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString.contains("sso")) != false){
                // TODO: add padding to top
                // self.parent.padding(      )
            } else {
                // Remove the padding
            }
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
        
        func getQueryStringParameter(url: String, param: String) -> String? {
          guard let url = URLComponents(string: url) else { return nil }
          return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
        }
        
        func insertQueryItems(url: String, key: String, value: String) -> URL?{
            var urlObject = URLComponents(string: url)
            var urlComponents = urlObject?.queryItems
            if(urlComponents == nil){
                urlComponents = []
            }
            urlComponents?.removeAll(where: { $0.name == key })
            urlComponents?.append(URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value))
            urlObject?.queryItems = urlComponents
            return urlObject?.url
        
        }
    }
}

class LocationManagerService: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var manager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    @Published var enabled: Bool = false
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print("location changed")
        location = locations.first
        let user_lat = String(format: "%f", location?.coordinate.latitude!)
        let user_long = String(format: "%f", location?.coordinate.longitude)
            //THIS FUNCTION UPDATES
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print(error)
    }
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        enabled = CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to unwrap the optional(s).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I put a ! after it to unwrap it, I got an error saying I have to remove the ! again. So I am in a loop of errors.

Comment: Error: Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')

Comment: I don't know where exactly the error occurs but it talks clearly about ***'CLLocationDegrees?' (aka 'Optional')***

Comment: fyi makeUIView needs to init a WKWebView and return it and there is no need to save it in a property.

Answer (score 0):

`location?.coordinate.latitude!` is wrong.  You're location is `Optional<CLLocation>` which you need to unwrap, ensure isn't nil first `guard let location = locations.last else { return }` to get an honest, non-optional location (the most recent one delivered to your delegate).  `locations.first` returns an optional because the locations array might have 0 locations in it, i.e. it might not have a first one.

You can't force unwrap the latitude, because latitude is a CLLocationDegrees aka Double, and if you have a location at all, then it's coordinate will have an honest, non-optional latitude.

```
guard let coordinate = locations.last?.coordinate else { return }
let user_lat = String(format: "%f", coordinate.latitude)
let user_long = String(format: "%f", coordinate.longitude)
```

An expression like `location?.coordinate.latitude` is an `Optional<CLLocationDegrees>` but you can't force unwrap that with a ! at the end because it's the *location* that is optional, not the latitude, and you optionally-chained that with the ? after location, which leaves the whole expression of type `Optional<CLLocationDegrees>`.

Comment: `locations.first` you probably meant `locations.last`